# Bokeh: disable Auto-ranging while using Edit Tools

Tags: python, bokeh

I've included the [PolyDrawTool](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tools.html#bokeh.models.tools.PolyDrawTool) in my Bokeh plot to let users circle points. When a user draws a line near the edge of the plot the tool expands the axes which often messes up the shape. Is there a way to freeze the axes while a user is drawing on the plot?

I'm using bokeh 1.3.4

**MRE:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import string

from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, LabelSet
from bokeh.models import PolyDrawTool, MultiLine


def prepare_plot():
    embedding_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100, 2)), columns=['x', 'y'])
    embedding_df['word'] = embedding_df.apply(lambda x: ''.join(np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase), (8,))), axis=1)

    # Plot preparation configuration Data source
    source = ColumnDataSource(ColumnDataSource.from_df(embedding_df))
    labels = LabelSet(x="x", y="y", text="word", y_offset=-10,x_offset = 5,
                      text_font_size="10pt", text_color="#555555",
                      source=source, text_align='center')
    plot = figure(plot_width=1000, plot_height=500, active_scroll="wheel_zoom",
                      tools='pan, box_select, wheel_zoom, save, reset')

    # Configure free-hand draw
    draw_source = ColumnDataSource(data={'xs': [], 'ys': [], 'color': []})
    renderer = plot.multi_line('xs', 'ys', line_width=5, alpha=0.4, color='color', source=draw_source)
    renderer.selection_glyph = MultiLine(line_color='color', line_width=5, line_alpha=0.8)
    draw_tool = PolyDrawTool(renderers=[renderer], empty_value='red')
    plot.add_tools(draw_tool)

    # Add the data and labels to plot
    plot.circle("x", "y", size=0, source=source, line_color="black", fill_alpha=0.8)
    plot.add_layout(labels)
    return plot


if __name__ == '__main__':
    plot = prepare_plot()
    show(plot)
```

[image: GIF of the issue]

Comment: Yeah I can try to make an MRE. I just realized I may have worded that badly. The axes expand while positioning the line, but snap back if the line ends up within the original bounds. The change is only permanent if the drawn line ends up outside the original bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PolyDrawTool` actually updates a `ColumnDataSource` to drive a glyph that draws what the users indicates. The behavior you are seeing is a natural consequence of that fact, combined with Bokeh's default auto-ranging `DataRange1d` (which by default also consider every glyph when computing the auto-bounds). So, you have two options:

- Don't use `DataRange1d` at all, e.g. you can provide fixed axis bounds when you call `figure`:

  ```
  p = figure(..., x_range=(0,10), y_range=(-20, 20)
  ```

  or you can set them after the fact:

  ```
  p.x_range = Range1d(0, 10)
  p.y_range = Range1d(-20, 20)
  ```

  Of course, with this approach you will no longer get any auto-ranging at all; you will need to set the axis ranges to exactly the start/end that you want.
- Make `DataRange1d` be more selective by explicitly setting its `renderers` property:

  ```
  r = p.circle(...)
  p.x_range.renderers = [r] 
  p.y_range.renderers = [r]
  ```

  Now the `DataRange` models will only consider the circle renderer when computing the auto-ranged start/end.